# Как правильно работать с Foundation Zurb?

Tags: gulp, sass, npm, bower, foundation

Доброго дня. Только начал осваивать `Foundation Zurb`. Делаю по этой [инструкции](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html). У меня выкачиваются `node_modules` на 650мб. Проект получается весит около 700мб. Как можно использовать эти `node_modules` для всех проектов, без выкачки по 600мб для каждого?

Пробовал использовать `foundation-sites-template`, по сути самое то, но там нет сборки проекта, пути до JS получаются лютые. (`bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/...`) и в директории множество лишних файлов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из способов, который мне всецело подошел - это развернуть полноценный проект (`Foundation Zurb`) и в других проектах уже создавать директорию-ссылку на `node_modules` в развернутом проекте.